# How to load words into Anki for randomly generated cards?

Tags: javascript, html, anki

I want to create an Anki card that randomly selects a word from a table to practice conjugation. I understand random generation isn't optimal for Anki, but I'd rather not add bloat to my deck by adding hundreds of very similar cards. I will use [this](https://github.com/SimonLammer/anki-persistence) to store the random value from front to back.

The table of words is within the Anki deck elsewhere under the tag *verb*. I was wondering if their was some way to access the fields of all of the cards with the tag and randomly select one of them. If this isn't possible, is there an alternative that doesn't involve copying the verbs into a javascript map/array in the card code?